# Passing a file as an argument and reading the data

Tags: c, file

So I am trying to write a C code that takes in a file name as the argument and reads the file and stores it into an array. I have tried but failed epically :(

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Here is what I came up with (I know it may be completely off track :/ )

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char content[500];
   int k=0;
   FILE* inputF;
   inputF = fopen("argv[0]", "r");

   do {
       fscanf(inputF, "%c", &content[k]);
       k++;
   } while (content[k] != EOF ); 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: always, check if the file is opened correctly by using `if(inputF == NULL) { printf("error");} else { // do stuff }`.

Comment: This is a typical beginner question. I have started a proposal for a new Q&A site where beginner should be able to ask their questions without any negative attitudes or RTFM comments. Experts should answer question there because they want to teach newcomers. If you like the idea become a [follower](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52242/beginner-programmers?referrer=YHFcRobXPDGfDpFmz1HCvA2)

Answer (score 3):

You passed `"argv[0]"` string to `fopen`, I'm sure that isn't the name of you file you are trying to open.

You should pass a pointer to a string that contains the file name.

```
inputF = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

Also note the usage of `argv[1]` not `argv[0]`.

`argv[0]` contains the full filepath and name of the executable and `argv[1]` the first string entered as command line parameter.

Comment: so argv[0] is the executable file name and argv[1] is the file that was passed into it as argument? Sorry for asking dumb questions but how exactly do I pass a pointer to a string that contains the file name? something like... char *filename = argv[1]; ?? Thanks for helping!

Comment: `argv[1]` is a pointer to a string. String is the command line argument. You use it with [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/). `fopen(argv[1], "r"); == fopen("firstargument.txt", "r");`

Comment: Okay :) I changed it and when I run it via the command prompt it returns "a"... when I compile I get no errors so I am not sure what else is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points to help get you started:

`argc` is the number of arguments, and the first `argv` pointer is the name of the executable file. The second is what you want.

You have to check that your file pointer is valid before trying to use it.

Maybe look at using `fgetc` to read each character, and test for EOF.

You need to check that you don't overrun your `content` buffer.

If you're stuck, here's an example of a main loop using a do while:

```
do {
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    content[a] = ch;
    a++;
} while (ch != EOF && a < 500);
```

This will store an EOF (if found) in your array.

Comment: how would I test this?
    do {
        content[k] = '\0';
        k++;
    } while (content[k] != EOF || k < 500);
??

Comment: Here's the first bit to go from, if you use a do while loop: `do { ch = fgetc(inputF); ... ... } while ( two conditions... );`